# how to store all values for a every keys in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

As you can see in the picture that for different dates has different medicines
like for

```
2019-12-27 Medicine ALTISGPT => "72 u/L"
2019-12-26 Medicine ALTISGPT => "74 u/L"
2019-12-25 Medicine ALTISGPT => "74 u/L"
```

I want to map MedicineName to all values of that medicine with different dates like

```
ALTISGPT =>["72 u/L","74 u/L","74 u/L"]
```

So I tried to create a HashMap and thought to push the values if the same name occurs.

**SO FIRSTLY I ADDED EVERYTHING TO ARRAYLIST, THEN MATCHED AND ADDED IN VECTOR**

```
mUserDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("Medicines");

final HashMap<String,  Vector > Med=new HashMap<>();
mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                //DATES childDataSnapshot.getKey()
                Vector<String> v=new Vector();

                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot2 : childDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // "MEDICINE NAME" childDataSnapshot2.getKey()
                    arrayList.add(childDataSnapshot2.getKey());

                }}}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
```

Then I did this:

```
    for(int i=0;<arrayList.size();i++){
    mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                //DATES childDataSnapshot.getKey()
                Vector<String> v=new Vector();

                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot2 : childDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // "MEDICINE NAME" childDataSnapshot2.getKey()
                    if(arrayList.get(i).equals(childDataSnapshot2.getKey()))
                       v.add(childDataSnapshot2.getValue().toString());


                }}}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});

        Med.put(childDataSnapshot2.getKey(),v);
        }
```

**BUT ONE MORE PROBLEM I GET TO KNOW THAT FIREBASE IS ASYNC SO HOW TO SOLVE THIS,THAT'S WHY I THINK MY ARRAYLIST IS EMPTY
I SAW SOME BUT COULDN'T FIG OUT, iS THERE SOMETHING ONCOMPLETE**

[image]

Comment: I think rest of your logic seems correct but main problem is the async that is downloading values to your mobile from firebase takes time and till then every other thing has worked sequentially so you push empty to arrayList before you get the firebase value

Comment: yes can you tell how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below to get your result:

```
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("Medicines");
final HashMap<String, Vector> Med = new HashMap<>();

mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot2 : childDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // "MEDICINE NAME" childDataSnapshot2.getKey()

                Vector vector;

                if(Med.containsKey(childDataSnapshot2.getKey())) {
                    vector = Med.get(childDataSnapshot2.getKey());
                } else {
                    vector = new Vector();
                    Med.put(childDataSnapshot2.getKey(), vector);
                }

                vector.add(childDataSnapshot2.getValue(String.class));
            }
        }

        //Here Med contains all the data 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

***No need to use your second query inside loop. Remove that***

Comment: Thanks for optimizing this, one more thin arraylist is empty due to async of firebase how to solve that

Comment: Which `arraylist`? I didn't use any `arraylist`. You get all the data from `Med`

Comment: No need to use 2nd part, Remove it. You get all the data from `Med` HashMap

Comment: But    vector.add(childDataSnapshot2.getValue(String.class)); will be empty due to that async property

Comment: @Rohitgupta, Please replace your above code with my one.

Comment: OK . I was just confused by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048957/empty-arraylist-firebase-data-retrieval

Comment: That is different case. If you do the above task in separate place and want to use the result in another place then you have to handle this. In your current situation the above code is enough

Comment: I used the above code and after running that I tried to Toast Med.size() It returned 0

Comment: Where you checked?

Comment: Checked here: `//Here Med contains all the data`

Comment: I used on btn clicklistener then to put data it is now working  thanks